# Creating a dataframe in pandas by multiplying two series together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

Say I have two series in pandas, series A and series B. How do I create a dataframe in which all of those values are multiplied together, i.e. with series A down the left hand side and series B along the top. Basically the same concept as this, where series A would be the yellow on the left and series B the yellow along the top, and all the values in between would be filled in by multiplication:

http://www.google.co.uk/imgres?imgurl=http://www.vaughns-1-pagers.com/computer/multiplication-tables/times-table-12x12.gif&imgrefurl=http://www.vaughns-1-pagers.com/computer/multiplication-tables.htm&h=533&w=720&sz=58&tbnid=9B8R_kpUloA4NM:&tbnh=90&tbnw=122&zoom=1&usg=__meqZT9kIAMJ5b8BenRzF0l-CUqY=&docid=j9BT8tUCNtg--M&sa=X&ei=bkBpUpOWOI2p0AWYnIHwBQ&ved=0CE0Q9QEwBg

Sorry, should probably have added that my two series are not the same length. I'm getting an error now that 'matrices are not aligned' so I assume that's the problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can edit your question and add some code and errors or results.

Answer (score 5):

You can use matrix multiplication dot, but before you have to convert Series to DataFrame (because [dot method on Series implements dot product](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html)):

```
>>> B = pd.Series(range(1, 5))
>>> A = pd.Series(range(1, 5))
>>> dfA = pd.DataFrame(A)
>>> dfB = pd.DataFrame(B)
>>> dfA.dot(dfB.T)
   0  1   2   3
0  1  2   3   4
1  2  4   6   8
2  3  6   9  12
3  4  8  12  16
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a DataFrame from multiplying two series of unequal length by broadcasting each value of the row (or column) with the other series.  For example:

```
> row = pd.Series(np.arange(1, 6), index=np.arange(1, 6))
> col = pd.Series(np.arange(1, 4), index=np.arange(1, 4))
> row.apply(lambda r: r * col)
   1   2   3
1  1   2   3
2  2   4   6
3  3   6   9
4  4   8  12
5  5  10  15
```

Answer (score 3):

First create a DataFrame of 1's. Then broadcast multiply along each axis in turn.

```
>>> s1 = Series([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> s2 = Series([10,20,30])
>>> df = DataFrame(1, index=s1.index, columns=s2.index)
>>> df
   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  1
2  1  1  1
3  1  1  1
4  1  1  1
>>>> df.multiply(s1, axis='index') * s2
    0    1    2
0  10   20   30
1  20   40   60
2  30   60   90
3  40   80  120
4  50  100  150
```

You need to use `df.multiply` in order to specify that the series will line up with the row index. You can use the normal multiplication operator `*` with s2 because matching on columns is the default way of doing multiplication between a DataFrame and a Series.

Comment: This one feels the cleanest to me, because when you use the indices of s1 and s2 to define the index and columns of the ones dataframe (df in example), it is a visual cue to which series you used as index and which one as columns, and also because you can build it up step by step and see why it works.

Answer (score 1):

So I think this may get you most of the way there if you have two series of different lengths. This seems like a very manual process but I cannot think of another way using *pandas* or NumPy functions.

```
>>>> a = Series([1, 3, 3, 5, 5])
>>>> b = Series([5, 10])
```

First convert your *row* values `a` to a DataFrame and make copies of this Series in the form of new *columns* as many as you have values in your *columns* series `b`.

```
>>>> result = DataFrame(a)
>>>> for i in xrange(len(b)):
            result[i] = a
   0   1
0  1   1
1  3   3
2  3   3
3  5   5
4  5   5
```

You can then broadcast your Series `b` over your DataFrame `result`:

```
>>>> result = result.mul(b)
   0   1
0  5   10
1  15  30
2  15  30
3  25  50
4  25  50
```

In the example I have chosen, you will end up with indexes that are duplicates due to your initial Series. I would recommend leaving the indexes as unique identifiers. This makes programmatic sense otherwise you will return more than one value when you select an index that has more than one row assigned to it. If you must, you can then reindex your row labels and your column labels using these functions:

```
>>>> result.columns = b
>>>> result.set_index(a)
   5   10
1  5   10
3  15  30
3  15  30
5  25  50
5  25  50
```

Example of duplicate indexing:

```
>>>> result.loc[3]
   5   10
3  15  30
3  15  30
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the DataFrame.dot method, you need to transpose one of the series:

```
>>> a = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> b = pd.Series([10, 20, 30])
>>> a.to_frame().dot(b.to_frame().transpose())
    0   1   2
0  10  20  30
1  20  40  60
2  30  60  90
3  40  80 120
```

Also make sure the series have the same name.