# Pandas dataframe.dot division method

Tags: python, matrix, pandas

I am trying to divide two series of different length to return the matrix product  dataframe of them.

I can multiply them using the dot method ([from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19571460/1842478)):

```
# Create series
average_read_intervals = pd.Series([10,20,30,40],
                                   index=['a','b','c','d'])
region_lengths = pd.Series([100,200,300,400,500,1000],
                           index=['z','y','x','w','v','u'])

# Convert to dataframes
R = pd.DataFrame(region_lengths)
A = pd.DataFrame(average_read_intervals)

# Dot multiplication
R.dot(A.T)
       a      b      c      d
z   1000   2000   3000   4000
y   2000   4000   6000   8000
x   3000   6000   9000  12000
w   4000   8000  12000  16000
v   5000  10000  15000  20000
u  10000  20000  30000  40000
```

I've tried the div method, but this just fills the dataframe with NaNs:

```
In [17]: R.div(A.T)
Out[17]: 
    0   a   b   c   d
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
u NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
v NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
w NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
x NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
y NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
z NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Likewise the standard division operator also returns the same result:

```
In [18]: R / A.T
Out[1]: 
    0   a   b   c   d
0 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
u NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
v NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
w NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
x NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
y NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
z NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

So I'm a bit stumped as to what the correct solution is to my problem.

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do an element wise division operation you can divide the values of each data frame like so:

```
matrix_div = pd.DataFrame(R.values/A.T.values, index=R.index, columns=A.index)
```

which produces the desired matrix of

```
     a   b          c     d
z   10   5   3.333333   2.5
y   20  10   6.666667   5.0
x   30  15  10.000000   7.5
w   40  20  13.333333  10.0
v   50  25  16.666667  12.5
u  100  50  33.333333  25.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can in pandas, or at least not like that. `div` is an elementwise operation, similar to `mul`, not a matrix operation like `dot` (try `A.mul(A)` or, equivalently `A * A`).*

Matrix division (multiplication by the inverse) is only possible if the matrix in question is [nonsingular](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599121/why-cant-you-divide-matrices), which your `A` certainly isn't as it's not square.

Numpy has a function to [compute the inverse of a matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.inv.html) that you could use if your matrices were a different shape.

That said, in your case you basically want to broadcast `average_read_intervals` over some currently non-existent columns of `R`, which you could engineer by changing the shape of `R` through duplicating its column `len(average_read_intervals)` times.

```
# Make R into a 6 by 4 matrix with the correct column headings.
R = R.join([R.rename(columns={0: col}) for col in average_read_intervals.index]).ix[:, 1:]
R
      a     b     c     d
z   100   100   100   100
y   200   200   200   200
x   300   300   300   300
w   400   400   400   400
v   500   500   500   500
u  1000  1000  1000  1000


# Divide by Series (broadcast over D)
R / average_read_intervals

     a   b          c     d
z   10   5   3.333333   2.5
y   20  10   6.666667   5.0
x   30  15  10.000000   7.5
w   40  20  13.333333  10.0
v   50  25  16.666667  12.5
u  100  50  33.333333  25.0
```

But there are almost certainly better ways to do this. (Hoping someone will jump in :)

* This isn't always true, as they will [broadcast](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#matching-broadcasting-behavior) depending on the operands' shapes.

Comment: thanks that works for the lovely simple example I've got, but wouldn't replicate for my main data (odd). Solved it using the other answer, but your explanations were extremely helpful. Cheers!

Comment: Great, glad it helped. And @aus_lacy's answer (using ndarrays) was definitely better than mine. :)